# Mmap allocating more than one page

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, kernel

So I'm on x86-64 linux, and when I try to `mmap` one byte, I get way more than one page. Here's my thinking: When I allocate one byte, I should be able to access `PAGE_SIZE` bytes after that. That's how paging works, right? I confirmed that `PAGE_SIZE` on my system is 4096. But still, the following code doesn't segfault:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *p = mmap(0, 1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE
                                                    |MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        p[5000] = 3;
}
```

5000 there is some arbitrary value greater than `PAGE_SIZE`. My understanding is, the line `p[5000] = 3` should generate a page fault, and the page fault handler should realize that the page doesn't belong to me. But it doesn't happen. The code works. So is `mmap` giving me more than one page?

Comment: The fact that your code doesn't segfault does not imply that more than `4096` bytes are being allocated.

Comment: Ok, so is it something to do with the way paging is setup on my system?

Comment: If you access memory outside of your allocation, the behavior of your program is undefined from that on.

Comment: While saying UB is technically correct, it's not very helpful. I did some experiments and it seems that Linux, for some inexplicable reason, rounds up the mapping to nearest page plus one. This actually smells like a bug. (even a 2 page mmap gets three pages returned).

Comment: *I confirmed that `PAGE_SIZE` on my system is 4096*  Is that the only page size available on your system?

Comment: Correction to my previous comment. After reading what's going on, it looks like every single mapping returned is coalesced with some other nearby mapping. I incorrectly assumed that linux ASLR would be better than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is, the line p[5000] = 3 should generate a page fault

No, dereferencing `p` to a memory that was not allocated is *undefined behavior*: it does not imply that your program must segfault.

For example, `p[5000]` may still access some memory your process owns and therefore no segfault occurs.

> The code works. So is mmap giving me more than one page?

No, the fact that you don't get a segfault does not mean either that the code is correct.

From `mmap`'s manual page:

> The length argument specifies the length of the mapping.

Comment: Ah, so if i try to map a value smaller than `PAGE_SIZE`, it's not guaranteed that I get only one page?

Comment: @HiltonCartwright one page is the minimum it must allocate.

Comment: @HiltonCartwright You're going to get one page, but you're not guaranteed that there isn't some other allocation next to your allocation. In the tests I've done with your code `mmap` always returned a bit of memory that was just next to some other allocation that was done earlier (either by the dynamic linker or the standard library).